# Can I run JSR 352 batch jobs on WebSphere Application Server traditional Version 8.0?

Tags: java, websphere, batch-processing, websphere-liberty, jsr352

I am having below doubts,

1. In my project we are using WebSphere Application server 8.0.0.7, now we are planing to host JSR 352 application in my WebSphere Application server 8.0.0.7. Is it possible to host JSR 352 applications on WAS 8.0.0.7? If yes can you please guide me how to do that.
2. Currently I am using Liberty Profile Server to Host JSR 352 applications.Is it possible to install Liberty Profile server on WAS 8.0.0.7?
3. whether there is a admin console option available for JSR 352 under WebSphere Application Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot run JSR 352 applications on WebSphere Application Server 8.0.  You can only run them on WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: Hi Scott,
Actually in http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/rep_ca/7/897/ENUS213-137/ENUS213-137.PDF site they mentioned that "IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 delivers
enhanced Liberty profile capabilities and introduces a new lightweight Liberty only offering for Web Profile applications". It means that we can deploy and test jsr 352 applications in WAS 8.5.5?

Comment: You cannot run JSR 352 apps in Version 8.5.5 of WebSphere Application Server traditional.  The terminology is a bit confusing.  The single product "WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5" provides two different runtime environments.   One is now called "WebSphere Application Server traditional" and had previously been referred to as "full profile".  The other is now "WebSphere Liberty" and had previously been referred to as the "Liberty profile".   But just to be clear, JSR 352 support only exists in WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: Is it possible to install Liberty profile on top of WAS 8.0.0.7or on WAS 8.5?

Comment: No, it is not possible.    There is some ability to manage Liberty servers side by side with traditional servers from the traditional admin console, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: I am using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8/wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942 and I am usning batchMangement-1.0 and adminCentere-1.0. I am getting     below error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load conflicting versions of features "com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.el-3.0" and "com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.el-2.2".  The feature dependency chains that led to the conflict are: com.ibm.websphere.appserver.batch-1.0 -> com.ibm.ws.persistence-1.0 ->

Comment: May I know how to solve this issue so that i want to login to Admin Center to get Admin Console for Liberty Profile.

Comment: Please raise a new question (including your <featureManager> config from your server.xml) and I'll look for it.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I have created new question to it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440242/addinig-admincenter-1-0-to-featuremanager-in-server-xml-giving-errors)