# Including both adminCenter-1.0 and batchManagement-1.0 features in server.xml giving feature conflict error in Liberty 8.5.5.8

Tags: java, websphere, batch-processing, websphere-liberty, jsr352

I am using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8/wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942 and I am using batchManagement-1.0 and adminCenter-1.0 in my featureManager list like below

```
<featureManager>        
            <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
            <feature>batchManagement-1.0</feature>
            <feature>batch-1.0</feature>        
            <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
            <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        </featureManager>
```

server.xml is showing below warning

['adminCenter-1.0' --> 'restConnector-1.0' --> 'jaxrs-1.1' --> 'com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javaeeCompatible-6.0'] and ['batchManagement-1.0' --> 
 'batch-1.0' --> 'com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javaeeCompatible-7.0'] features are in conflict. Select a compatible set of features.

May I know how to solve this problems?

My Server.xml is like below,

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>        
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>batchManagement-1.0</feature>
        <feature>batch-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>        
    </featureManager>

    <!--  The default self-signed SSL certificate in this example
      is intended only for development use and not for production. -->

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="Liberty"/> 

    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="ibm/api">
       <user name="bob" password="bobpwd"/>
     </basicRegistry>


    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <!-- Batch persistence config.  References a databaseStore. -->
    <batchPersistence jobStoreRef="BatchDatabaseStore"/>

    <!-- The database store for the batch tables.  -->
    <!-- Note this database store is referenced by the batchPersistence element. -->
    <databaseStore dataSourceRef="batchDB" id="BatchDatabaseStore" schema="JBATCH" tablePrefix=""/>

    <!-- Derby JDBC driver -->
    <!-- Note this library is referenced by the dataSource element -->
    <library id="DerbyLib">
        <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/resources/derby"/>
    </library>
    <dataSource id="batchDB" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ" syncQueryTimeoutWithTransactionTimeout="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib"/>
        <properties.derby.embedded createDatabase="create" databaseName="${server.config.dir}/resources/RUNTIMEDB" password="pass" user="user"/>
    </dataSource> 

    <!-- Posgres DB Entries 
    <dataSource id="PostgresSample" jndiName="jdbc/SKLocal" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
       <jdbcDriver javax.sql.XADataSource="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource"  libraryRef="PostgresJDBCLib"/>
          <properties databaseName="postgres" password="****" portNumber="5433" serverName="localhost" user="postgres"/>
   </dataSource>   
   <library id="PostgresJDBCLib">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/resources/posgres" includes="*.jar"/>
   </library>-->

    <!-- Posgres DB Entries END -->
    <!-- DB2 Data Source Starts -->
    <dataSource connectionSharing="MatchOriginalRequest" id="DB2DataSource" jndiName="jdbc/db2" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
      <jdbcDriver javax.sql.XADataSource="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource" libraryRef="DB2JCC4Lib"/>      
       <!--  <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="IDSSTG" password="****" portNumber="50000" serverName="****" user="****"/>-->
       <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="PNENDB2" password="****" portNumber="50000" serverName="****" user="****"/>
    </dataSource>
    <library id="DB2JCC4Lib">
      <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/resources/db2" includes="*.jar"/>
     </library>
    <!--  DB2 Data Source Ends -->

    <library id="cacheLibrary">
          <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/resources/cache" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>        

   <application id="myapp" location="ReadingFromDBSampleWAR.war" name="ReadingFromDBSampleWAR" type="war">
     <classloader commonLibraryRef="cacheLibrary"/>
   </application>

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <webApplication id="ReadingFromDBSampleWAR" location="ReadingFromDBSampleWAR.war" name="ReadingFromDBSampleWAR"/>
</server>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Looks like this problem is similar a fix that went into 8559.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI52094

If you update to an 8559 version of Liberty this should solve your problem.
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/

**Extra Info:**

Check out this link of all the Liberty features:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html

This is a link to the batchManagement feature:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_batchManagement-1.0.html

From the link you can see that servlet-3.1 and batch-1.0 are enabled by the batchManagement feature. Then if you look into the servlet-3.1 article you will see that adminCenter-1.0 is enabled by that feature as well.

Comment: I have removed it but when I run the batch I am getting errors.                         [ERROR   ] CWWKD0292E: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/Synchronization
[ERROR   ] CWWKD0292E: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/transaction/JTASynchronizationListener
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl.start:211'
javax.batch.operations.JobStartException: javax.batch.operations.BatchRuntimeException: Failed to load JPA PersistenceServiceUnit
 at com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperator

Comment: That sounds like another problem with your server.xml. I am unable to diagnose from just this error message without seeing the entire server.xml. Are you setting up a multiple server environment or a single server environment?

Comment: I have added the server.xml in my question, I am using single server only which is installed in my local machine.it was working fine before experimenting with adding adminCenter-1.0 to <featureManager>

Comment: I would try upgrading to Liberty 8.5.5.9. The fix to the problem I pasted in the updated answer is not in the 8.5.5.8 version you are using.

Comment: I am able to resolve the above mentioned issue but I how can I resolve the issue mentioned in my question that is how install the adminCenter-1.0 and access the Liberty profile admin console page in WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8/wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942?

Comment: may I know how upgrade Liberty 8.5.5.8 to 8.5.5.9?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to Fixpack 8.5.5.9 for Liberty,

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24041819#Liberty

Use the fixpacks that match the way Liberty was installed.

Comment: May I know where can I find the documentation to upgrade from existing 8.5.5.8 to 8.5.5.9?

Comment: The above link has upgrade instructions for the various installation methods:  [JAR archive](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_inst_fixpack.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5), [InstallationManager (IM)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ins_install_fixes_dist.htm) install, etc.